# Trying to make a Custom UITableViewCell with a UITextField becomeFirstResponder when Editing

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiresponder

I have a `UITableViewController` with custom `UITableViewCell`s that contain a `UITextField`. When switching the table view into edit mode, I add a new cell to the bottom of the table and would like to make this cell `becomeFirstResponder`. My `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method checks for this bottom cell, so I just added the line:

> [cell.theTextField becomeFirstResponder];

Which I believed should work. However, when the table view is first displayed, it does not seem to be working. BUT if I select the cell (making it the first responder), then go out of edit mode (causing a `resignFirstResponder` within my code), I can then go back into edit mode and magically it becomes the first responder as I would expect!

Note that even if I end editing mode with a different cell selected (they all have text fields) and go out of edit mode, then back in, it still works, ***as long as*** at some point I had made the last cell `becomeFirstResponder` (by selecting it).

So, my guess is that when it first becomes the first responder, there is something getting set either in the table view or some place else that wasn't originally set, and from then on it makes this work.

Anyone have any ideas as to what may be going on here?

Answer (score 1):

The first `becomeFirstResponder` call fails because the cell doesn't have a superview yet. The table view adds the cell as its subview after you return it from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I suggest you make this call somewhere else. If you already have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, you could implement `didMoveToWindow:` and call `[self becomeFirstResponder]` there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there are a couple of things. 1) How would I only select this for that one cell (and not all of them), 2) I tried just adding this to my custom cell class and it didn't do anything. I also tried putting this in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: where I can do an 'if' for only that cell, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Hm, that's tough. How do you add the cell when entering the editing mode? If all else fails, you can perform `becomeFirstResponder` after a delay, but that's ugly, fragile and should be done only as a last resort.

Comment: Here is the relevant part: [self.tableView beginUpdates]; if (editing) { [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathForNewLabel] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; } [self.tableView endUpdates];